# Function notation with set of mappings valid or not? I have never seen one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have seen notations in maths scripts similar to the following:

$f: \{1,2\} \rightarrow \{3, 4\}$

$1 \mapsto 3$

$2 \mapsto 4$

but not once compact mappings similar to the relation in the set notation {(1,3), (2,4)}

Would you say the following definition is ambiguous or even incorrect?

$f: \{1,2\} \rightarrow \{3, 4\}, \{1 \mapsto 3, 2 \mapsto 4\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to know exactly what you mean here.  So I don't think it's ambiguous or incorrect...

Of course,  you might instead write: $f(1)=3$ and $f(2)=4$...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I would also agree with your notation. Is there someone else who agrees on my formulation or has doubts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point. Instead of introducing the new notation
$$ f: \{1,2\} \rightarrow \{3, 4\}, \{1 \mapsto 3, 2 \mapsto 4\}$$
why not simply use the shorter, already established notation
$$ f: \{1,2\} \rightarrow \{3, 4\}, \ 1 \mapsto 3, \ 2 \mapsto 4 \ \ ?$$

---

You could also use
$$ f = \{1 \mapsto 3, 2 \mapsto 4 \}$$
which is a perfectly reasonable notation as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: You are right, this one is shorter. But I would like to place the mappings in a structure/container, where a set would make sense for me.